# Java (Graphics2D): triangle drawn by created Graphics2D not visible until second repaint

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, graphics2d

I have the following minimal code to draw a line with an arrow head:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class StateBtn extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -431114028667352251L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        // enable antialiasing
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);


        // draw the arrow
        Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(0, getHeight()/2, 20, getHeight()/2);            
        drawArrowHead(g2, line);
        g2.draw(line);

        // If I call repaint() here (like in my answer below), it works

    }

    private void drawArrowHead(Graphics2D g2d, Line2D.Double line) {  
        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();

        tx.setToIdentity();
        double angle = Math.atan2(line.y2-line.y1, line.x2-line.x1);
        tx.translate(line.x2, line.y2);
        tx.rotate((angle-Math.PI/2d));  

        Polygon arrowHead = new Polygon();  
        arrowHead.addPoint(0,5);
        arrowHead.addPoint(-5,-5);
        arrowHead.addPoint(5,-5);

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        g.setTransform(tx);   
        g.fill(arrowHead);
        g.dispose();
    }

}
```

It is created like this:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4085389089535850911L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main frame = new Main();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocation(0, 0);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        StateBtn stateBtn = new StateBtn();
        stateBtn.setBounds(200,200,35,35);
        contentPane.add(stateBtn);
    }
}
```

The line is drawn properly but the arrow head is invisible until I call repaint(). The problem is that the element is a draggable one, so I would have to call repaint() twice every time the position is changed. This would make the code more complex and the GUI would be laggy.

Why can't the arrow head just be drawn together with the line? Is there really no one who can help me?

Comment: More context might help. Let's see your [mcve] code where you use this code. Side not (unrelated to the problem at hand): never call `setBackground(...)` from within a painting method. That belongs elsewhere, perhaps in a constructor or in an event listener, but never in a painting method.

Comment: OK, I have extended the code a bit.

Comment: I think, yes. The method drawArrowHead is from another thread on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You've not posted a true [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so it's impossible to know what you could be doing wrong, but there's no need for the kludge you've used in your answer, where you re-call `repaint()` within paintComponent. If you still need help with *your own* code, then please post a valid MCVE, code we can compile and run without modification. For an example of what I mean by MCVE, please read the [MCVE link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and look at the example MCVE that I've posted in my answer below.

Having said this, understand that generally Swing graphics are passive, meaning that you would have your program change its state based on an event, then call `repaint()` and this *suggests* to the Swing repaint manager to call paint. There is no guarantee that painting will occur, since repaint requests that have "stacked", that are backing up due to many being called in a short time, may be ignored.

So in your case, we can use your code and modify it to see how this works. Say I give my JPanel a MouseAdapter -- a class that is both a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener, and in this adapter I simply set two Point instance fields, p0 -- for where the mouse was initially pressed, and p1 -- for where the mouse drags or releases. I can set these fields and then call repaint, and let my painting methods use p0 and p1 to draw my arrow. So the mouse adapater could look like so:

```
private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
    private boolean settingMouse = false;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            return;
        }
        p0 = e.getPoint();
        p1 = null;
        settingMouse = true; // drawing a new arrow
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        setP1(e);
        settingMouse = false; // no longer drawing the new arrow
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        setP1(e);
    }

    private void setP1(MouseEvent e) {
        if (settingMouse) {
            p1 = e.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

And then within my painting code, I'd use your code, modified to make it use my p0 and p1 points:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

    if (p0 != null && p1 != null) {
        Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(p0.x, p0.y, p1.x, p1.y);

        drawArrowHead(g2, line);
        g2.draw(line);          
    }

}
```

The whole shebang would look like so:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StateBtn extends JPanel {
    // constants to size the JPanel
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 650;
    private static final int AH_SIZE = 5; // size of arrow head -- avoid "magic"
                                            // numbers!

    // our start and end Points for the arrow
    private Point p0 = null;
    private Point p1 = null;

    public StateBtn() {
        // create and add a label to tell the user what to do
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Click Mouse and Drag");
        label.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 42));
        label.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 50));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(label); // add it to the center

        // create our MouseAdapater and use it as both MouseListener and
        // MouseMotionListener
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

        // only do this if there are points to draw!
        if (p0 != null && p1 != null) {
            Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(p0.x, p0.y, p1.x, p1.y);

            drawArrowHead(g2, line);
            g2.draw(line);
        }

    }

    private void drawArrowHead(Graphics2D g2d, Line2D.Double line) {
        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();

        tx.setToIdentity();
        double angle = Math.atan2(line.y2 - line.y1, line.x2 - line.x1);
        tx.translate(line.x2, line.y2);
        tx.rotate((angle - Math.PI / 2d));

        Polygon arrowHead = new Polygon();
        arrowHead.addPoint(0, AH_SIZE); // again avoid "magic" numbers
        arrowHead.addPoint(-AH_SIZE, -AH_SIZE);
        arrowHead.addPoint(AH_SIZE, -AH_SIZE);

        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        g.setTransform(tx);
        g.fill(arrowHead);
        g.dispose(); // we created this, so we can dispose of it
        // we should **NOT** dispose of g2d since the JVM gave us that
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // size our JPanel
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private boolean settingMouse = false;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // if we press the wrong mouse button, exit
            if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                return;
            }
            p0 = e.getPoint();  // set the start point
            p1 = null;  // clear the end point
            settingMouse = true; // tell mouse listener we're creating a new arrow
            repaint();  // suggest a repaint
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            setP1(e);
            settingMouse = false; // no longer drawing the new arrow
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            setP1(e);
        }

        private void setP1(MouseEvent e) {
            if (settingMouse) {
                p1 = e.getPoint(); // set the end point
                repaint();  // and paint!
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        StateBtn mainPanel = new StateBtn();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("StateBtn");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This code is what I meant by my example of a MCVE. Actually it's a little large for a decent MCVE, but it will do.  Please compile and run the code to see that it works. If this doesn't help you, if you still must use a kludge with your repaint calls, then I urge you to create your own MCVE and post it with your question, and then comment to me so I can see it.

An aside, someone questioned if it was OK to create a new Graphics object as you're doing within `drawArrowHead(...)` method, and yes this not only OK, it's the preferred thing to do when dealing with AffineTransforms, since this way you don't have to worry about down-stream effects that the transform might have on border and child components that might share the original Graphics object. Again this is OK, as long as you follow the rule of disposing Graphics objects that **you yourself create**, and not disposing Graphics objects **given to you by the JVM**.

Comment: OK, I understood. I have updated my question. Can you please help me?

Comment: Sorry, I still was not able to make my code working properly. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems, there is no other way than to call repaint again. I did like this at the end of the paintComponent-method:

```
if (repaint == false) {
    repaint = true;
} else {
    repaint = false;
    repaint();
}
```

Hence, it repaints exactly one time. But is there no cleaner solution?

Comment: This is not needed, and in fact `repaint()` should never be called from within a paintComponent method.